# TypeScript infer template literal from const template literal

Tags: typescript, template-literals

I trying to type a REST API using fancy TypeScript template literals. I have a system that works for `const` string types and `const` Javascript template literal types, but not for Javascript template literals with unknown values.

Consider the following recursive path parser.

```js
type PathVariable = string;
type ExtractPathVariable<T extends string> = T extends `:${string}`
    ? PathVariable
    : T;
type PathParts<Path extends string> = Path extends `/${infer Rest}`
    ? PathParts<Rest>
    : Path extends `${infer Start}/${infer Rest}`
    ? [ExtractPathVariable<Start>, ...PathParts<`${Rest}`>]
    : Path extends `${infer Item}`
    ? [ExtractPathVariable<Item>]
    : never;
```

It gives expected results for some cases

```
// A == ["short", "url", "path"]
type A = PathParts<"/short/url/path">;
const b = `/short/url/path` as const;
// B == ["short", "url", "path"]
type B = PathParts<typeof b>;
// C == ["short", "${y}", "path"]
type C = PathParts<"/short/${y}/path">;
const d = `/short/${45}/path` as const;
// D == ["short", "45", "path"]
type D = PathParts<typeof d>;
```

However, the case I'm most interested in (because that's how I call my API), it doesn't work.

```js
let y: unknown;
const e = `/short/${y}/path`;
// E == never
type E = PathParts<typeof e>;
```

Is there a way to make `PathParts<typeof e>` work? A result of `E == ["short", string, "path"]` or `E == ["short", unknown, "path"]` would be fine.

Comment: See updated answer for TS4.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### UPDATE FOR TypeScript 4.3:

Issue [microsoft/Typescript#43060](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43060) has been marked fixed by pull request [microsoft/Typescript#43361](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/43361), which should be released with TypeScript 4.3. At that point, your code above will work (as long as you use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) as I mention below):

```
let y: unknown;
const e = `/short/${y}/path` as const;
// const e: `/short/${string}/path`
type E = PathParts<typeof e>;
// type E = ["short", string, "path"]
```

You can see it in action here: [Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.0-dev.20210329&ssl=13&ssc=1&pln=20&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBACghsAFgNTgJwJZwEYBtoC8UAzsJgHYDmA3AFCiRQCiAHmXAMbDxKqY74APABUoENhHIATYiTIYqAPihFR44JJlQABgC4AJAG9SFSgF9ttKFAD8sBCnRY8EK1F1RhdBtB6J4aMDEgn5iEtKyJgqUykSh6pqy2gD0RgoAZhBoUABKEKQWbnZ+AUGCeaSKbh7x4VraaeSZ2QDKwOjAZqmGGVm5+Z2W1nYA2qzsXH58zkJtHYoANFAAdKslHcENhhWDigC61fZIYRoROo3NUACSGgC2hcNQY2xonNwO0wIQgjcQt-uHcgQABuWTotHwwCgIA8AFdyABrcgAewA7uQ6BxkeRSGIVDpksREMjAt0QF0wA5tFA4LIsTjgHRkskoPTcRAPCkiSTgN0olQKVT6OBoEx8etAsEfMj0mJFEyWT5mPiRgAibmBVVLfmUJaqylIVUHWi0IA)

---

#### Previous answer for TS 4.2:

Sorry, but I think this is currently not possible as of TypeScript 4.2.

First, to even get close to this behavior you'd need to use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to tell the compiler that you'd like `e` to be inferred as a template literal type and not just `string`.  While there is a consistency argument that, like `const foo = "abc"` is inferred as `"abc"`, so `` const bar = `abc${x}` `` should be inferred as type `` `abc${string}` `` or the like, as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#41631](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41631), this change ended up [breaking too much real world code](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/41631#issuecomment-782301471).  So you need the `as const`:

```
const e = `/short/${y}/path` as const
// const e: `/short/${string}/path`
```

But that's about as far as we can go.  You're trying to match a template literal type with multiple `infer` locations against another template literal type with a "pattern" literal like `` `${number}` `` (where pattern literals are implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#40598](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40598).  But according to [microsoft/TypeScript#43060](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43060) this is not possible (it mentions `` `${number}` `` instead of `` `${string} ``, but the same situation occurs for all pattern literals):

```
type Simple<T> = T extends `${infer F}/${infer L}` ? [F, L] : never
type Works = Simple<`foo/bar`> // ["foo", "bar"];
type Broken = Simple<`foo/${string}`> // never
type AlsoBroken = Simple<`${string}/bar`> // never
```

That issue hasn't been classified as a bug/limitation/suggestion yet, but it is related to [microsoft/TypeScript#43243](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43243) which is considered a suggestion.  For now there doesn't seem to be a mechanism in place to allow this sort of inference to work.  I haven't been able to find any workaround that behaves reasonably, either.

If you care about seeing this happen you might want to go to either of those issues and give a  and/or describe why your use case is compelling.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/C4TwDgpgBACghsAFgNTgJwJZwEYBtoC8UAzsJgHYDmA3AFCiRQCiAHmXAMbDxKqY74APABUoENhHIATYiTIYqAPihFR44JJlQABgC4AJAG9SFSgF9ttKFAD8sBCnRY8EK1F1RhdBtB6J4aMDEgn5iEtKyJgqUykSh6pqy2gD0RgoAZhBoUABKEKQWbnZ+AUGCeaSKbh7x4VraaeSZ2QDKwOjAZqmGGVm5+Z2W1nYA2qzsXH58zkJtHYoANFAAdKslHcENhhWDigC61fZIYRoROo3NUACSGgC2hcNQY2xonNwO0wIQgjcQt-uHcgQABuWTotHwwCgIA8USoKigACJEBBcLgAPaI6hQZLJKBIDCyKTo-LkADkUJRuDAtA46PIpDECJSxEQ6MC3RAXTADm0UDgsjpDKhuPxiEJUGJpIpUHSGBYUAwwFooqFjIgHhZbI5Rjh5mSPKQlno4GgLQwtzAQmEsU8J0S5x6TT6ADEuhc+gAZCy2J4upaevbuKBA0FoE2MADq7IA1rIiObLUJtOl0ejkth0NplKKRojU5ilojM2hEXtvKaoAAhNDomOSBGJq3fFNp7p6iw5vGhrIR6AAQVwxHRNbrDYTFubgi2HYzWa7IZBvdoK6AA)